# Find all declarations that are visible in the library in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

I'm using mirrors, and I'm trying to find all the top level functions that are visible from the library.

Basically, all the top level functions that are callable if someone would import that library.

So I tried this:

```
  final visibleMethods = currentMirrorSystem().isolate.rootLibrary.declarations.values
      .where((d) =>
          !d.isPrivate &&
          d.isTopLevel &&
          d is MethodMirror)
      .toList();
```

But this doesn't seem to include functions that are exported into the library, for example, I have:

`export 'package:my_package/some_tasks.dart' show myOtherTask;`

exported into the library. But it is not included in the `visibleMethods` list with my current implementation.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't export into a library. You can only export from a library or import into a library. You have to grab the import and export statements and reflect on the referenced libraries recursively.